# application does not run on version higher than 4.1 in android

Tags: android, version

My application works well on 4.1 version and below. but when tried testing it on higher versions it keeps crashing. mostly when buttons are used to call new activity. 
uses permission in my manifest is as below

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

i am new to android and this is my first application please help me figure it out. thanks in advance.

EDIT my logcat is as follows. hope this helps.

```
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:45.933: E/lights(672): write_led_info failed to open -1
11-06 12:49:46.623: E/videowall-TranscodeReceiver(9272): broadcastMSG : android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
11-06 12:49:46.643: E/vwengine(9272): stopTranscoding
11-06 12:49:48.353: E/SMD(275): DCD OFF
11-06 12:49:50.323: E/AudioResampler(266): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
11-06 12:49:50.863: E/AudioResampler(266): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
11-06 12:49:51.353: E/SMD(275): DCD OFF
11-06 12:49:51.393: E/AudioResampler(266): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
11-06 12:49:52.193: E/AudioResampler(266): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
11-06 12:49:52.673: E/AudioResampler(266): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
11-06 12:49:54.363: E/SMD(275): DCD OFF
11-06 12:49:55.083: E/AudioResampler(266): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672): Writing exception to parcel
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13292)
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2058)
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
11-06 12:49:56.373: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-06 12:49:56.433: E/dbadapter(13552): ***********Database Created*****************
11-06 12:49:57.363: E/SMD(275): DCD OFF
11-06 12:49:57.573: E/TypeFaces(13552): Typeface not loaded.
11-06 12:49:57.583: E/TypeFaces(13552): Typeface not loaded.
11-06 12:49:58.983: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(672): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
11-06 12:50:00.363: E/SMD(275): DCD OFF
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672): Writing exception to parcel
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13292)
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2058)
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
11-06 12:50:01.423: E/DatabaseUtils(672):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-06 12:50:01.773: E/dalvikvm-heap(13552): Out of memory on a 28702816-byte allocation.
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.application1/com.example.application1.CreateSlideActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:718)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:382)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at com.example.application1.CreateSlideActivity.onCreate(CreateSlideActivity.java:187)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    ... 11 more
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    ... 23 more
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:586)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3564)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3493)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:469)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
11-06 12:50:01.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    ... 26 more
11-06 12:50:02.133: E/android.os.Debug(672): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
11-06 12:50:03.363: E/SMD(275): DCD OFF
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat of the crash

Comment: try removing android:targetSdkVersion="19" this line and check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

That tag is not related to permissions but simply states the minimum sdk version. You need to tell us where the crash happens as otherwise nobody will be able to help. You can get this information from i.e. logcat or (which I would recommend anyway) from a crash reporting library such as Acra (https://github.com/ACRA/acra).

Comment: I have edited my question and added the logcat. sorry for the delay. please check it please help me find a solution.

Comment: Have you reviewed your logcat? Your app crashes because an out of memory error so it seems you are either loading an image which is too large or you have generated a memory leak before.

Comment: What is also a bit odd but might be unrelated to your app (don't know if you are using a database) is the permission warning from the database utils.